# Modify a vcpkg triplet file, how can I rebuild?

Tags: vcpkg

We use a custom triplet file `MyTriplet.cmake` with some specific settings. Everything is built but now we need to change one setting in the triplet file. The problem is, when we re-run `vcpkg install` it reports everything is already built.

I know the nuclear option of deleting my entire *vcpkg* directory and starting again, but this means downloading everything again too.

I could also create a new triplet `MyTriplet2' and build that, but it doesn't seem ideal either.

In the past I have tried to manually remove directories but either I don't delete enough, or I delete too much and then end up having to start from scratch anyway.

We build about 30 different ports so a solution that doesn't involve iterating over each port would be preferred! Is there one key folder I can remove that will make vcpkg think "MyTriplet hasn't been built yet?"

Answer (score 1):

your options:

- delete the folder `<vcpkgroot>/installed/` if you only have this one triplet.
- remove all installed ports manually
- use manifest mode in cmake + binary caching. This automatically removes all ports if the hash changed. Since the triplet is part of the hash it will automatically rebuild everything.